# how do I put event.index within jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Working on a slideshow and there's a callback for mouseover called panelMouseOver. I can log the event.index in my Dev Console, but I'm a little too noobish with jQuery to know how to put that number within the selector. This is what I have which does not work, but should give you an idea about what I'm trying to do. "data-index" is an attribute on the slide divs with a number for each one. Thanks!

```
            panelMouseOver: function(event) {
                console.log(event.index);
                $("div[data-index='event.index'] h2").fadeOut();
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *really* close, you just need to do some concatenation:

```
$('div[data-index="' + event.index + '"] h2').fadeOut();
```

---

**If** this event is attached to the `div` in question, though (I can't be sure from the info in the question), it may be much simpler:

```
panelMouseOver: function(event) {
    $(this).find("h2").fadeOut();
},
```

...or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("div[data-index='" + event.index + "'] h2").fadeOut();
```